# react native init gera o app.js sem o render()

Tags: react-native

o app.js esta assim:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> teste
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>piroca de </Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <ReloadInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <DebugInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Read the docs to discover what to do next:
              </Text>
            </View>
            <LearnMoreLinks />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

sou iniciante no react native, nas aulas e no proprio site do react native ele mostra que sempre tem a função render(), essa é uma outra versão do react native?

Answer (score 0):

Nos exemplos que você encontra pesquisando na internet geralmente o componente extende a classe components, por isso existe o render. Exemplo:

```js
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Olá, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

No caso do seu código, ele não é um componente, ele é uma função. Neste caso, não tem o render.

Aqui tem alguns exemplos de códigos parecidos:

https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html